# Elasticsearch index comma-separated values and use them as filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-mapping

I am currently indexing the `element` field as `"element" : "dog,cat,mouse"` with the following configuration:

**ES config**:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "search_synonyms": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": [
                    "graph_synonyms",
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                ],
            },
            "comma" : {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "comma"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "graph_synonyms": {
                ...
            }
        },
        "normalizer": {
            "normalizer_1": {
                ...
            }
        },
        "tokenizer" : {
            "comma" : {
                "type" : "pattern",
                "pattern" : ","
            }
        },
    }
},
```

**Fields mapping**:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "element": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "normalizer_1"
        }
        ................
    }
}
```

The value `dog,cat,mouse` is used afterwards as a filter but I want to separate them and use each value as a separated filter. I tried to use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) feature and made the following changes but I'm still not sure what else should I do.

```
"element": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "normalizer_1",
    "fields": {
        "separated": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "comma"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: provided answer, based on my understnading , let me know if you hv further ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a field where you are storing the value as `dog,cat,mouse` and you need them separately like `dog`, `cat` and `mouse` for that you can simply use the text field to store them which uses [default standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which split tokens on comma `,`.

**[analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to show the tokens**

```
{
    "text": "dog,cat,mouse",
    "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

**tokens generated**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "dog",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "cat",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "mouse",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 13,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

As per comment, Adding a sample on how to define `element` field so that `standard` analyzer is used, note currently its defined as `keyword` with normalizer, hence `standard` analyzer is not used.

Index mapping

PUT /your-index/

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { 
        "element": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: My application provides an `element` dropdown where I can select `dog,cat,mouse` and use this value as filter for searching. I want to be able to select `dog`, or `cat`, or `mouse` as filter values. Note that comma isn't the only separator for this `element` field. I could also have `dog&cat&mouse`

Comment: @shAkur thanks for your comment, I just tried `dog&cat&mouse` and standard analyzer tokens them separately as well :)

Comment: Is standard analyzer used by default on the `element` field?  What changes should I make to the field mapping? Thanks for your patience, I am really new with elasticsearch.

Comment: @shAkur, you need to define your `element` field as `text` in your mapping, will add a sample in my answer.

Comment: Should I ditch the `keyword` type with normalizer completely? As I said this is currently use for filtering purposes and I'm afraid it'll mess things up

Comment: @shAkur, you can try otheriwise create an another field and store this information that way your both the functionalties will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214666/discussion-between-shakur-and-prerna-gupta).

Comment: but it does not work if it only nums